# Стоит ли включать имя сущности в имя метода репозитория?

Tags: symfony

Как лучше именовать методы репозитория,
так:

```
EntityRepository::getListBySomeField()
```

Или так:

```
EntityRepository::getEntityListBySomeField()
```

Желательно аргументировать ответ. Так же интересно было бы узнать масштаб проекта для которого тот или иной подход оказался более подходящим и специфику, повлиявшую на решение о выборе одного из них.

Comment: Хотелось бы сначала услышать аргументированный вопрос. Почему у вас возникла эта идея? Какие преимущества вы видите?

Comment: Мне больше нравится первый вариант, потому что он короче и не избыточен. Я не сталкивался с ситуацией, где метод репозитория вызывался бы в отрыве от имени сущности но у меня не большой опыт в Symfony (порядка 4 месяцев). Второй вариант мне предлагают как более понятный и удобный для чтения и более соответсвующий чистому коду.

Comment: Т.е. два раза писать Entity (для тех, кто с первого раза не понял что это относится к Entity) вы считаете более понятным и удобным?

Comment: Нет, написал же выше - мне его предлагаЮТ как более понятный и удобный для чтения. Мне для понятности достаточно и первого варианта.

Comment: @PixeliaBuilder возможно ваш оппонент не понимает, что репозиторий предполагает манипуляции сущностями одного типа. Или он видит ваш код только в интерфейсе пулреквеста и  ему лень прочитать название файла :-) В любом случае нажимайте на DRY.

Answer (score 3):

Повторяющиеся префиксы или суффиксы или внезапные вставки в середину имени метода, константы, переменной, класса или пакета чаще всего означают, что надо выделить новую абстракцию.

Например:

```
$userId, $userName -> class User{$id, $name}

function getFromDb, function putInDb -> class Db {function get, function put}

class CliCommand, class CliOptions -> namespace cli {class Command, class Options}
```

Но в сообществе php-разработчиков очень популярны бесполезно повторяющиеся суффиксы и префиксы. Их можно и нужно удалять. Ведь у любой переменной, функции, класса есть доступный контекст.

Взгляните:

```
$user = $usersRepo->selectOne(); // что же возвращает метод selectOne?

class Programmer {
    function writeCode() {...} // кто же пишет код? 
}

namesapce eshop {
    class Order {...} // Заказ или порядок?
}

namespace SQL {
    class Order {...} // Порядок или заказ?
}
```

Хороший код не нуждается в повторениях. Правильно названные пакеты, классы и методы, переменные и константы создают простой и выразительный язык для описания бизнес логики (и не только). Принцип [DRY](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself) актуален и для названий тоже.

Желание писать хороший код от масштаба проекта не зависит. А большие проекты прекрасно живут с отвратительным кодом внутри.

---

P.S. Подумайте про Repository в имени класса. Если он лежит в пакете repositories, то может быть не стоит повторяться?

Comment: Отличное объяснение. Спасибо.